bip_utils and metamask
I am trying to learn to use the python package named bip_utils.
Here is the code
from bip_utils import Bip39MnemonicGenerator, Bip39SeedGenerator, Bip44

mnemonic = Bip39MnemonicGenerator().FromWordsNumber(Bip39WordsNum.WORDS_NUM_12)
seed_bytes = Bip39SeedGenerator(mnemonic).Generate("ahfdohfsodfhsdoifh")
bip44_mst_ctx = Bip44.FromSeed(seed_bytes, Bip44Coins.ETHEREUM)
bip44_acc_ctx = bip44_mst_ctx.Purpose().Coin().Account(0)

print('Mnemonic '+str(mnemonic))
print('Address '+bip44_acc_ctx.PublicKey().ToAddress())

Now I install metamask and recover wallet using the mnemoic I generated.
However metamask shows a totally different eth address than I print in the last line.
How do i get the eth address that metamask uses in the python code using bip_utils?

Use the first derivation path.
